# Getting text input value with jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

so i've been trying to get the value from an input but it comes out as undefined. Any clues why?

```js
$("#logForm").on("submit", function (e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        let textInput = $('input[name="userID"]');
        let userName = textInput.val();
        console.log(userName);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="logForm">
  <input type="text" name="userId">
  <button type="submit">ENTER</button>
</form>
```

Pretty new at JS in general so it's very likely that I'm missing something/doing something dumb.

Comment: hi, perhaps match the case of the field (`userId` instead of `userID`)

Comment: Attribute names are case sensitive.

Comment: @IronMan Oh my God it was that. I was stressing so hard because of something this small hahaha, thank you so much! I feel pretty dumb to be honest hahaha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your selector doesn't match the attribute value. It should be `userId`:

```js
$("#logForm").on("submit", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  let textInput = $('input[name="userId"]');
  let userName = textInput.val();
  console.log(userName);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="logForm">
  <input type="text" name="userId">
  <button type="submit">ENTER</button>
</form>
```